# ContentResolver and "IN" statement in "where" condition

Tags: java, android

I am trying to get cursor for a list of contacts based on therir ids. I am not really sure how to use "IN" statement with an array of arguments. What I currently have causes an error.

```
public Cursor GetContacts(String[] ids)
{
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    try
    {
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
        };

        String where = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " IN ?";

        String[] selectionArgs = ids;

        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

        return cr.query(uri, projection, where, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    String message = ex.getMessage();
    Log.e("mine", "Error: " + message, ex);

    return null;
    }
```

Error: near "?": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT _id, display_name, has_phone_number FROM view_contacts WHERE ((1)) AND ((_id IN ?)) ORDER BY display_name

Comment: Which error does it cause?

Comment: Are you trying to return one result based on one id or several results based on an array of ids?

Comment: @LarryMcKenzie, several results based on an array of ids. That's why I use "IN" clause

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I didn't test this but I think you need to condense your ids into a single comma separated string in order to insert it into your query.

```
public Cursor GetContacts(String[] ids)
{
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();

    try
    {
        Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;

        String[] projection = new String[] {
                ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
                ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER
        };

        String where = ContactsContract.Contacts._ID + " IN (?)";

        String[] selectionArgs = {StringUtils.join(ids, ", ")};

        String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME;

        return cr.query(uri, projection, where, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    String message = ex.getMessage();
    Log.e("mine", "Error: " + message, ex);

    return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We can add selectionArguments in where part itself

```
public Cursor getCursor() {
 Uri contentUri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContentProviderDb.CONTENT_URI, TABLE_FEEDS);
        String feedList =  "27","79","78","77","31";

        String where = FEED_ID + " IN ("+feedList+") AND " + PLACE_ID + "=\"" +placeId+"\" AND " + PROFILE_ID + "=" + userId ;

        return context.getContentResolver().query(contentUri, null, where, null, TIMESTAMP + " DESC");
}
```

Here If the selection argument value is String need to add escape character.