# How to use selectionArgs[] in contentResolver.query()

Tags: android, sqlite

I have to select from the ContactsContract table of an android device some contacts, checking the LOOKUP_KEY value of the contact.

I have to do a single query, to which I pass many LOOKUP values.
So far i did something like the code you see beloew, that of course is not correct:

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
                                      ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                                      null, 
                                      ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY + " =?", 
                                      new String[] {"f2hsk", "djkf7fk", "hf74fnk2"}, 
                                      null);
```

I tried also using ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY + " IN?" but I get a synthax error.

I hope is clear what I have to achieve.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Do you know how you would write this in pure SQL?

Comment: I write this way: SELECT x from FROM y
WHERE z IN (value1, value2, etc); Isn't it correct?

Answer (score 3):

Each questionmark is going to be replaced with the corresponding parameter value from the `selectionArgs` array.

```
Cursor cursor = contentResolver.query(
                                      ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI, 
                                      null, 
                                      ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY + "=? or " + ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY + "=? or " + ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY + "=?", 
                                      new String[] {"f2hsk", "djkf7fk", "hf74fnk2"}, 
                                      null);
```

Comment: Thank you for you help. So, if I have 100 selectArg should I write 100 times ContactsContract.Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY + "=? or "...
It's seems not "clean"

Comment: No, it was just an example of how to use `selectionArgs` in the query. For the `IN` condition see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23795007/321106)